# ORACLE-Why WHERE clause is not working on UNION?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to UNION two column :

> T1.STATUS, T8.REASON in one column , WHERE T1.OUTLET_ID = T8.OUTLET_ID
>   AND T1.ENTRY_DATE = T8.ENTRY_DATE

But when I add WHERE clause in UNION of two table it shows error:

> ORA-00904: "T8"."ENTRY_DATE": invalid identifier

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT T1.OUTLET_ID,T1.STATUS,T1.ENTRY_DATE  FROM T_ORDER_DETAIL T1 
    UNION 
    SELECT T8.OUTLET_ID,T8.REASON,T8.ENTRY_DATE FROM  T_NON_PRODUCTIVE_SALES T8 
) 
WHERE T1.OUTLET_ID = T8.OUTLET_ID AND T1.ENTRY_DATE = T8.ENTRY_DATE
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do here?

Comment: What are trying to do? may be it should be JOIN instead of UNION.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rework the query like that:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM (
 SELECT T1.OUTLET_ID id,
        T1.STATUS res,
        T1.ENTRY_DATE dt 
   FROM T_ORDER_DETAIL T1, 
        T_NON_PRODUCTIVE_SALES T8
  WHERE T1.OUTLET_ID = T8.OUTLET_ID 
    AND T1.ENTRY_DATE = T8.ENTRY_DATE
  UNION 
 SELECT T8.OUTLET_ID id,
        T8.REASON res,
        T8.ENTRY_DATE dt 
   FROM T_ORDER_DETAIL T1, 
        T_NON_PRODUCTIVE_SALES T8
  WHERE T1.OUTLET_ID = T8.OUTLET_ID 
    AND T1.ENTRY_DATE = T8.ENTRY_DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT T1.OUTLET_ID,T1.STATUS,T1.ENTRY_DATE  FROM T_ORDER_DETAIL T1 
    UNION 
    SELECT T8.OUTLET_ID,T8.REASON,T8.ENTRY_DATE FROM  T_NON_PRODUCTIVE_SALES T8 
) 
WHERE T1.OUTLET_ID = T8.OUTLET_ID AND T1.ENTRY_DATE = T8.ENTRY_DATE
```

When you execute your query, the subquery return a table of records with column names  `OUTLET_ID ,STATUS ,ENTRY_DATE`. So in short you get a `table` with these columns.

In the outer query when you write the condition

> WHERE T1.OUTLET_ID = T8.OUTLET_ID AND T1.ENTRY_DATE = T8.ENTRY_DATE

Oracle doesnot understand whats `T1` and `T8`. Because the outer query treats the result from your subquery as a `table`. And there is no such name given to your table so it gives the error. As explained earlier by others you can make a join and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery gives only one result set and thus you can't `JOIN` like that. rather change your query to be like

```
SELECT T1.OUTLET_ID,T1.STATUS,T1.ENTRY_DATE,
T8.OUTLET_ID,T8.REASON,T8.ENTRY_DATE AS T8_ENTRY_DATE
FROM T_ORDER_DETAIL T1 
JOIN  T_NON_PRODUCTIVE_SALES T8 
ON T1.OUTLET_ID = T8.OUTLET_ID AND T1.ENTRY_DATE = T8.ENTRY_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use INNER JOIN instead of UNION:

```
SELECT 
    t1.outlet_id, t1.status, t8.status, t1.entry_date
FROM 
    t_order_detail t1 
INNER JOIN 
    t_non_productive_sales t8
ON t1.outlet_id = t8.outlet_id 
    AND t1.entry_date = t8.entry_date;
```